# Checking if in iterable is in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

You can check if anything is part of a an iterable with "in", it works for :

Tuples. I.E :

```
"foo" in ("foo", 1, c, etc) #Return True
```

Lists. I.E :

```
"foo" in ["foo", 1, c, etc] #Return true
```

Strings. I.E :

```
"a" in "ago" will #return true
```

Dict. I.E :

```
"foo" in {"foo" : "bar"} #return true
```

Can I do the reverse of this by checking if multiple substrings are in a single string?  As in, something along these lines:

```
x = "W", "e", "99"
z = "Welcome"
w in z
```

Ideally, I would like it to return True since one of the substrings are in in "Welcome".

Is there a built in function for something such as this?

-Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use `any` with a generator expression:

```
any(xx in z for xx in x)
```

`any` will short circuit, so if the first item in the iterable is in the string, the rest won't need to be checked.

Comment: Can you explain the syntax for this expression?  Is this expression called an 'any expression'.

Comment: @MattRumbel: [`any` is a normal built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) that takes any iterable input. You're passing it [a generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) which is sort of like a lazy list comprehension (read link for details).

Comment: What is the significance of using the double 'xx' rather than a single 'x'?  Both return True.

Comment: `xx` is just another variable name I picked for the items in the `x` iterable. In real code you should use better variable names. The generator expression is a bit confusing because of the two `in`s. The first is the operator testing if `xx` is a substring of `z`. The second is part of the `for` loop. It is parsed by Python as `(xx in z) for xx in x`